# Finding $f(x)$ in this integration, is there a formula for that?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

l’m stuck at this question because I couldn’t find $f(x)$ in this integration, is there a formula for that? Please help..

**Question:**

Given $$\int_{2}^{4} f(x) dx=2$$

and $$\int_{2}^{7} f(x) dx=11,$$

then $$\int_{4}^{7} (3f(x)+1) dx = ?$$

Comment: You don't need to know $f$ and can't. You can find the answer just using properties of the definite integral. What happens to the area under a graph when you triple the values of the function? When you add a constant to the function?

Comment: Answering this question requires the knowledge of basic properties of integrals. Have you ever heard anything about this fact: $$\int_{2}^{7}f(x)\,dx=\int_{2}^{4}f(x)\,dx+\int_{4}^{7}f(x)\,dx?$$ This, of course, implies that the function $f(x)$ is continous on the interval $[2,7]$.

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed. The OP has made an effort by trying to find the function $f$. This will not work, but it shows effort none-the-less.

Answer (score 2):

You need not find the $f(x)$. Follow the following rules

We have $$\int_{2}^{7} f(x) dx= \int_{2}^{4} f(x) dx + \int_{4}^{7} f(x) dx$$
Hence $$\int_{4}^{7} f(x) dx=\int_{2}^{7} f(x) dx- \int_{2}^{4} f(x) dx  $$
$$\implies \int_{4}^{7} f(x) dx=11-2=9$$

Now $$\int_{4}^{7} (3f(x)+1) dx = 3\int_{4}^{7} f(x) dx + \int_{4}^{7} dx = 27+3=30$$

Answer (score 1):

What you have is:
$$\int_2^4f(x)dx=2$$
$$\int_2^7f(x)dx=\int_2^4f(x)dx+\int_4^7f(x)dx=11\therefore\int_4^7f(x)dx=9$$
Now use this:
$$\int_4^7\left[3f(x)+1\right]dx=3\int_4^7f(x)dx+\int_4^7dx=3(9)+(7-4)=30$$